# How to add an iterative id column which goes up when a value in another column resets to 1 in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, iteration

I have a SQL table which has two columns called seq and sub_seq as seen below. I would like to add a third column called id, which goes up by 1 every time the sub_seq starts again at 1 as shown in the table below.

| seq | sub_seq | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 2 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 |
| 12 | 4 | 3 |
| 13 | 5 | 3 |
| 14 | 6 | 3 |
| 15 | 7 | 3 |

I could write a solution using plpgsql, however I would like to know if there is a way of doing this in standard SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  **sub_seq** is always a running sequence then you can use the [DENSE RANK](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-dense_rank-function/) function and order over the differences of two columns, assuming it will consistently uniform.

```
SELECT seq, sub_Seq, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY seq-sub_Seq) AS id
FROM tableDemo
```

This solution is based on the sample data you have provided, I think more sample data would be helpful to check the whole scenario.